# using 7z.dll for in-memory compression and decompression

Tags: vb.net, dll, compression

I am writing a compression interface for a Windows XP+ application. My requirement is to use the supported interfaces of 7-zip to perform compression and decompression of in-memory data, not file data. Currently, I have kluged together a program which writes the data to a temporary file on disk, invokes 7z.exe to compress or decompress the data to a second temporary file, then returns the contents of the second file; that works, but I would rather use 7z.dll directly. The programming language I have to use is similar to Visual Basic, and can use DLL functions exported from 7z.dll, or OLE objects. Can anyone point me to sample code in VB that uses 7-zip to perform compression/decompression on-the-fly?

Comment: `similar to VB`??  if it was in fact VB or C# you could use GZIP (part of NET) and just read/write the result to a stream - memory or file.

Comment: Have a look at [7Zip (LZMA) In-Memory Compression with C#](http://www.nullskull.com/a/768/7zip-lzma-inmemory-compression-with-c.aspx). You can compile that to a library and reference it in your VB.net code.

Comment: better if you go for http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/ for 7z dotnet (wrapped around native) dll. You can do what you are trying. You can also use LZMA sdk if you wish.